# Purpose of resistors from phase to phase on 480V motor

Tags: resistors, motor, three-phase

I have inherited a project with a motor circuit that I cannot figure out the purpose of some resistors.

It was initially designed for operation in Europe at 400V 50Hz. Since it is operating here in the US now it is operating at 480 60Hz. The motor is running 20% faster, but for this application it does not matter. The motor is controlled by a solid state device up stream that will swap the phases to open or close the motor. The motor is very small, FLA of 0.62 and will open and close about every 6 seconds.

If someone can give me a clue as the the purpose of the resistors, or a thread to start pulling as to why they are there, I would appreciate it

Thanks!

Here is the circuit:

[image: Motor Schematic]

Comment: The symbols you have there are MOV's, not resistors.  They are most likely there to clip spikes from the motor.  If they were resistors, they could be wastefully used to help the motor brake, but it has a physical brake on it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I had a chance to go on site and they were indeed MOV's and not resistors.